# i want to drag object(box2d) with the touch position in cocos2d+box2d iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, physics, box2d-iphone

Guys 
 i want to drag a box2d object from  touch move method in iphone

i have used the mouse joint but it is not working perfectly as object fluctuating  within it's place   like it is tied up with rubber

help is appreciated 
thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The mouse joint is essentially a rubber band.

Destroy the body temporarily while dragging and re-create it again in -(void)onTouchEnded.